# How to extract Specific string from a subject line in sfdc

Tags: apex, string

My requirement is to extract specific string from a email subject like.

My email subject always like:

> Fleet Invoice inv - account name

I need to extract account name from above subject line.

Always they use same specific template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apex [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) provides a lot of useful methods.

In your case, I'd use the `substringAfter(separator)` method to get the end of your String after the '-' character. Like this:

```
String accountName = yourSubject.substringAfter(' - ');
```